# Lightning for Gmail Drag and Drop

Tags: lightning, lightning-for-gmail

I am working on a lightning component that displays a list of records and allows users to reorder records as displayed on the component. I use the library Sortable to handle my drag and drop functionality, and load it in through a static resource. I want it to work on mobile and on computers using both mouse and touch screen. So far, it works as expected in the Salesforce1 app as well as on a Lightning app. However, when used in Lightning for Gmail, the drag and drop works with touch screen computers but not the mouse. After narrowing down the issue, I used the following code to determine that OnDragStart is not getting fired in Lightning for Gmail. Is there a way to enable Drag Events in Lightning for Gmail?

Controller:

```
onDragStart : function (component, event, helper) {
    console.log("Drag start fired.");
}
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="<Custom Controller>" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,clients:availableForMailAppAppPage">
    <div draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.onDragStart}">
        <p>
            Test
        </p>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```